# The service "security.authentication.provider.guard.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"

Tags: symfony4

i have a project developed with **symfony 4.3**,
i try to add the guard authentication service using **make:auth** command.

i have this line error :

> The service "security.authentication.provider.guard.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"
>
> User Deprecated: Auto-injection of the container for "App\Controller\SecurityController" is deprecated since Symfony 4.2. Configure it as a service instead.

in the **services.yaml**, i put these lines:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

# controllers are imported separately to make sure Services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: do you have a class `App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator`? if you do, it can't be found, which might indicate the wrong location, the wrong namespace, typo in the class name, ...

Comment: yes it exist
i found the mistake, when i checked the kernel file, the load of services.yaml is wrong